# Title bar contents becomes blank/invisible in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs

Ext JS : ver 6.5.2.463 theme-classic (6.2.1.167)
Browser : Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (64-bit)
OS : Window 10 (64bit)

Few days ago I start my application as usual but encounter an awkward behavior when I opened already collapsed panel in Chrome its title bar text was blank. I tried in on another browser it was working fine there. 
I tried it on another machine it was working fine there. but when the Chrome of other machine get updated the same problem is there too.
we updated our Ext JS version from 6.2.1.167(Classic) to 6.5.2.463(Classic) but the problem is still there. 
we create the similar UI on the fiddle and link is attached. so you can verify it.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2acg&view/editor
is there anyone else facing the same issue ?
To reproduce the issue:
1. Open the link to a fiddle.
2. Click on the expand button the title bar content will be shown.
3. Now click on the collapse then expand now content will disappear.

Screenshots are also attached.
[title bar is blank there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVSCw.png)

Comment: **Cannot reproduce** in the fiddle, using Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise (64bit). Neither in 6.5.2 nor in 6.2.1

Comment: a screenshot is attached as a proof if you ask I can send you the video.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go though with this config **[`collapseMode`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-collapseMode)** and also with code file of [`collapseMode`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/src/Panel.js.html#Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-collapseMode).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2am1)**, I have used your code and made some change as per your requirement. Hope this will help you or guide you to solve your problem.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    plugins: 'viewport',
    title: 'ViewPort Title',
    layout: 'fit',
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Expand',
        handler: function () {
            var panel = this.up('panel').down('#bottomPanel');
            panel.collapseMode = undefined;
            panel.expand();
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Collapse',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('panel').down('#bottomPanel').collapse();
        }
    }],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Center Panel Title',
            region: 'center',
            html: 'Sample center panel text'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'bottomPanel',
            title: 'Bottom Panel Title',
            region: 'south',
            height: 150,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: 'mini',
            collapsed: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: 'Sample bottom inner panel text'
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: it is fixed in the latest update of chrome. Now its working fine. thanks

Comment: Yes, I have checked your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2acg&view/editor) in `Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)` is working fine but in case someone get same issue then they will apply this **[solution](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2am1)**.